# Yii: Adding an alias variable to CActiveRecord instance

Tags: php, yii

My `User` class is derived from `CActiveRecord`. It has a field `email` mapped to a database and there is an extension which needs the variable to be named `mailaddress`.

How can I add a member variable named `mailaddress` under `User` class, so that it returns the value stored in `email`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a read-only [component property](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.component#component-property) to your `User` class:

```
public function getMailAddress() {
    return $this->email;
}
```